# load owl file java code using jena api

Tags: java, jena, owl

I have this code in `package oopn.ontology`

```
public class Ontology {

private static Ontology ontology = new Ontology();
public static OntModel ontologyModel; //this is the main of Ontology model
public static File ontologyFile; //this is the file of owl
public static String ontologyFilePath; //this is the path of owl file
public static JTree ontologyModelTree;
public static int saveAction;
public static String copiedText;
public static JTree tree;

private Ontology() {
}

public static Ontology getInstance() {
    return ontology;
}

public void resetOntology() {
    ontologyModel = null;
    ontologyFile = null;
    ontologyFilePath = null;
    ontologyModelTree = null;
}
```

Then this code to create ontology model:

```
public OntModel createOntologyModelFromFile(String owlFile) {
    InputStream in;
    in = FileManager.get().open(owlFile);
OntModel model1 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC);
OntModel model2 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
model1.read(in, "");
ontologyModel = model1;
    return model1;
}
```

To open file I have this one:

```
File openOntologyFile() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser;
    File chosenFile;
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File("mpasi.owl"));
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
    chosenFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (chosenFile != null) {
        //loadOntologyFile(chosenFile);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fileChooser, this);
    }
    //enableControls(true);
    Ontology.ontologyFilePath = chosenFile.getAbsolutePath();
    return chosenFile;
}
```

In main class this one:

```
public class Dss_mpasi extends javax.swing.JFrame {

JFileChooser fileDialog;
public Dss_mpasi() {
    initComponents();
    if (Ontology.ontologyFile != null) {
        Model tempModel ;
        if (Ontology.ontologyModel == null) {
            tempModel = Ontology.getInstance().createOntologyModelFromFile(Ontology.ontologyFilePath);
        } else {
            tempModel = Ontology.ontologyModel;
        }
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        tempModel.write(writer, "RDF/XML");            
    } 
}
```

but it still doesnt work... I hope some one can help me to make it work?

Comment: and what exactly is the issue/error you are getting?

Comment: aaah... its still cannot load my owl file...

Comment: Are you still unable to load the owl file? See my answer and let me know if the problem still persist.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help... my friends help me. And i just add this 

 codeOntology.getInstance().createOntologyModelFromFile("");

and in package oopn.ontology i give my owl path.... glad its work. Once more thank you..."D

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing 
`tempModel = Ontology.getInstance().createOntologyModelFromFile(Ontology.ontologyFilePath);` with something like this:

```
OntModel tempModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
FileManager.get().readModel( tempModel , Ontology.ontologyFilePath);
```

You might find the [selected answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011341/handle-more-than-one-owl-files-in-a-same-jena-application) useful for your purposes.